# Linux Permission: Sticky Bit Behaviors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, chmod

I am doing a practice task where I need to set appropriate file (and directory) permissions in Linux (Ubuntu), but I have encountered some weird behaviors that I do not understand.

---

I have done these as the root user:

For **/shared** I have set the directory permission to 1755, and `ls -l` showed drwxr-sr-t. This directory beings to root:root.

Added a file: **/shared/rnd/rnd-test**

For **/shared/rnd** and its contents I have set directory permission to 3770 (using `chmod -r`), and `ls -l` showed drwxrws--T. This directory as well as rnd-test beings to root:rnd.

**trent** is a user of the **rnd** group (confirmed with `id trent`).
**walter** is a user of the **rnd** group (confirmed with `id walter`).

As **trent**, created a file called **trent-test**.
As **walter**, created a file called **walter-test**.

---

Now `ls -l /shared/rnd` looks like this:
total 12
-rwxrwx--T 1 root   rnd 60 Jan 29 20:17 rnd-test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 trent  rnd 12 Jan 29 19:19 trent-test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 walter rnd  7 Jan 29 20:18 walter-test

---

As **trent**, `cat rnd-test` had no error.
As **walter**, `cat rnd-test` had no error.

---

### Problems

As **trent**, `echo 'trent' >> rnd-test` had no error. 
As **trent**, `echo 'trent' >> walter-test` had permission denied.

As **walter**, `echo 'walter' >> rnd-test` had no error. 
As **walter**, `echo 'walter' >> trent-test` had permission denied.

As **root**, `echo 'root' >> rnd-test` had no error. 
As **root**, `echo 'root' >> trent-test` had permission denied. 
As **root**, `echo 'root' >> walter-test` had permission denied.

---

##### Intentions

1. Task required that files created by one user can only be deleted by that user. (Sticky Bit)
2. Task required that group files should automatically owned by the group. (SGID)
3. Anyone outside of the group should not have access to the group files. (0 for other users)
4. Group members should be able to access their group files. (7 for the group)

Based on these requirements I set `0755` for **/shared** and `3770` for **/shared/***.

In fact, the requirements did not specify whether group members should be able to *modify* group files, but I am not clear why **trent** can modify **rnd-test** (owned by root:rnd) but not **walter-test** (owned by walter:rnd).

##### Sticky Bit Behaviors

If I were to set **/shared/rnd** permission to 1770 or 3770 (with the sticky bit), they were not able to modify (append).

If I were to set **/shared/rnd** permission to 0770 or 2770 (without the sticky bit), **trent** and **walter** was able to modify (append) **walter-test** and **trent-test** respectively.

I understand that some tools such as `vim` would delete the file first when trying to 'modify', but does `echo >>` also do that?

Answer (score 0):

I did more research, and found [this reply](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316463/cannot-edit-file-via-group-permission). Thanks to [@grifferz](https://askubuntu.com/users/19809/grifferz).

[@grifferz](https://askubuntu.com/users/19809/grifferz) mentioned that recent changes in Linux had further prevented users from writing other users' files even if they are in the same group.

> This protection is similar to protected_fifos, but it
> avoids writes to an attacker-controlled regular file, where a program
> expected to create one.

According to the `fs.protected_regular` [documentations](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt), while `protected_regular` is set to `2` (which my system had) it also applies to group writable sticky directories.

I changed it to `0` and the sticky bit behaved as it 'supposed' to be.

As for the 'writable' **/shared/rnd/rnd-test** (owned by **root**), it was because the **/shared** directory had `1755` set for permissions. I am not sure why but it magically allowed me to write **rnd-test**. It became un-writable (**before** `protected_regular` was changed) soon as I changed its permissions to `0755`.